# After serialization only the latest Customer is saved

Tags: c#, console, xml-serialization

I need to build a console app that allows a user to input (via terminal) details of a new user. This then needs to be written into XML through serialization (required). I constructed my customer class and have a method for building the new user - but it will always forget the last entry and only write one instance of user into my list.

Here is the method I built for adding the user:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace Hausarbeit_Autovermietung_Gierow
{
    class Addcustomer
    {
        public void AddCustomer()
        {
            
            var customer = new Customer();
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>() { customer };
            //DeserializeFromXML(customer);
            DeserializeFromXML(customers);
            var listCount = customers.Count;

            int maxID = FindMaxValue(customers, x => x.ID);

            Console.WriteLine("Vorname eingeben");
            customer.Firstname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Nachname eingeben");
            customer.Lastname = Console.ReadLine();
           // int ID;
            customer.ID = maxID + 1;
            
            //List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>() { customer };

            SerializeToXML(customer);
            SerializeToXML(customers);
            
            foreach (var cust in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Vorname: {cust.ID} {cust.Firstname} {cust.Lastname}");


                Console.ReadKey();

            }
            }

        static public void SerializeToXML(Customer customer)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));
            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"customer.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(textWriter, customer);
            }
        }

        public static void SerializeToXML(List<Customer> customers)
        {
            //var customer = new Customer("Vorname", "Nachname");
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Customer>));
            using (System.IO.TextWriter textWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"List.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(textWriter, customers);
            }

        }

       static List<Customer> DeserializeFromXML(List<Customer> customers)
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Customer>));
            List<Customer> customerslist;
            using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"List.xml"))
            {
                customerslist = (List<Customer>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
                return customerslist;
            }
        }

        public int FindMaxValue<T>(List<T> list, Converter<T, int> projection)
        {
            if (list.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty list");
            }
            int maxValue = int.MinValue;
            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                int value = projection(item);
                if (value > maxValue)
                {
                    maxValue = value;
                }
            }
            return maxValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't using deserialized list returned by `DeserializeFromXML` (and you don't use its argument, just remove it). I expect you would deserialize the list and then add new `customer` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you create a list containing only your new customer:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>() { customer };
```

Then you override it with a new instance by deserializing the xml:

```
DeserializeFromXML(customers);
```

But you never add the new customer (add this line):

```
customers.Add(customer);
```

So when you serialize, then new customer will be part of the list:

```
SerializeToXML(customers);
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for taking the time! I implemented customers.Add(customer); after providing all the values with no errors, but still yield only one element of customer , wenn the method is called again later (during runtime).

Comment: Look in your list.xml file after running this. Does the xml look correct? If so then look at the method you're using to display the list (maybe include this in your question).